# Error: id returned 1 exit status al usar clases en C++

Tags: c++

Quiero usar el método de acceso "Regresar()" para que me retorne el valor del tamaño a una clase tipo cadena que quiero crear pero al compilar me sale "Error: id returned 1 exit status". Ya antes me había pasado con varios datos pero era porque no los inicializaba al usar el constructor. En este caso el tamaño lo estoy inicializando en 0 con el constructor y esperaría que en la salida del programa imprima precisamente el valor de 0. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
 #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class CADENA{
private:
    int tam;
public:
    CADENA(){
        tam = 0;
    }
int Regresar();

};


int main(){
CADENA obj1;
cout<<obj1.Regresar();


return 0;
}

int CADENA::Regresar(){
return tam;
}
```

Comment: El programa funciona ¿Cuál se supone que es el problema?

Comment: El codigo que publicaste compila sin ningun problema. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LDoIwEEXXna9o4gYWGt0CmhB168I/GMqE1NDS9OGG8O210ERdzr3n3IwwZi9G1EOMO6nFGHpq5OS8JVQXgOCkHrhGRc6gIO58XwMkwTl@bW/3RzuDsfKNnipgUnvuUSXChG6UIkUZKsoZGEsVP/NjDWzJ7JMGSw5tUdawJAvWUKHUG59VPnWvU1LEFHzTrMfhXwNmyQer19klD2Svqn7Y/KW275YYPw "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: No queria compilar pero por razones que desconozco despues de algunos intentos ya compiló, misterios de la vida, gracias por sus respuestas